# dataGridView with comboBox

Tags: c#, datagridviewcombobox

I have existing combo box in my program, it has adding some events, its list of element is changing in time. I have dataGridView with dataGridViewComboBoxColumn. Now I want to add my combo box to one cell in dataGridView. How can I make it? I try several examples, which I find in the Internet, but I doesn't work..

## edit

I understand that it isn't possible. So, how can I add events to comboBox from dataGridViewComboBoxColumn?

## edit 2

```
 dataGridView.EditingControlShowing += dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing;

 private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing (object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e) {

    if ( e.Control is ComboBox) {
         ((ComboBox)e).event = new Handler;
    }
}
```

It seems to work good, but example I can't join this comboBox with some tag.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe you can add just any combo box to a DataGridView, as they aren't the same type.

The [DataGridViewComboBoxColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.aspx) type should automatically contain combo boxes of type [DataGridViewComboBoxCell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcell.aspx) for you to use.

If you want several combo boxes to contain the same data, you should implement it in a way that they are all using the same data source.

Comment: ok, so can I add some events to this combo box from DataGridViewComboBoxColumn?

Comment: The column itself doesn't have any events, but the individual cells do.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcell.aspx  You should be able to `AddListener thecell.OnClick AddressOf DoSomething`

Comment: so why when I do : ((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0]).onClik (or some other events) it doesn't exists.. ?

Comment: I think my code doesn't make different, because when I create DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();  cell have only few function. Maybe it is problem that I haven't the newest version .NET Framework.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem.  What I thought were listed as events were actually just internal protected methods.  The events that you need can be found here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview_events.aspx

Comment: but there are events for dataGrid, not dateGridViewComboBoxCell

Comment: Yes, and those datagrid events include events for the cells themselves.  What do you need exactly?

Comment: on comboBox SelectionItemChange and drawItem

Comment: Check out the `CellValueChanged` event for when the selected item changes (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged.aspx).  I don't know if drawing events will be so easy, but take a look at the `CellPainting` event (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting.aspx).

Comment: ok, thanks for help, in the Internet I found something. I add it to my post (if you are interesting). Generally, I must now which comboBox something change. But I don't know how I can recognize which comboBox is it. I don't know how I can connect this cell with some TAG

Comment: You can get a cell reference.  Please post with more information, I am curious.

Comment: Ah, I see.  What is the parent of that control?  Does that give you the cell?  You could also check the CellBeginEdit event on the datagrid, keep track of the cell reference, and use it on editingcontrolshowing.

Comment: when I show e.control.parent I see that is a some panel (odd). So maybe parent is the cell.